# How To Unblock Java ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, io, network-programming, objectinputstream

In my program I am using ObjectInput and ObjectOutput streams between a server and client. While working on my project I have made lots of side test classes and projects to test out new tools to me, sometimes when I make an ObjectInputStream it gets stuck there. I looked to oracle too see if they had an answer but I can't quite tell what I need to do.

Oracle says "A serialization stream header is read from the stream and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header."

I understand that data has to be serialized to be sent and my classes implement Serializeable though I have a feeling it doesn't do much to fix my problem. In some test projects I have been making my ObjectInputStreams goes fine, other times it freezes.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but normally each peer will create both an `ObjectOutputStream` and an `ObjectInputStream` on the same socket. It has to be done in that order, otherwise you can get a deadlock, and for the same reason it needs to be done as soon as you acquire the socket, at both ends.

Comment: Sorry for vague question but thanks for the answer. Just to make sure I'm picking up what you're saying is the server side has to initiate its object input/output streams before the client side? Also, does the order matter in when you make in or out first?

Comment: I can only suggest you read my answer again. I expressed myself clearly, and I addressed everything you have just raised.